# useContext returning null within child component, not parent component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-context

I have a parent component that can use `useContext()` to return the context, but if it's child component uses `useContext()` it returns the initial context (null in this case) and not the actual context.

I have no idea why this is happening because the parent component is wrapped in the provider, so the child must also have access to it.

Here's the code:

ApolloContext.js

```
import { createContext } from 'react';

export const ApolloContext = createContext(null);
```

index.js

```js
    <ApolloProvider client={client} store={store}>
      <Router>
        <ApolloContext.Provider value={client}>
            <App scopes={scopes} userId={userId} />
        </ApolloContext.Provider>
      </Router>
    </ApolloProvider>,
```

Parent component:

```
import { ApolloContext } from "../context/apollo/ApolloContext";

const ParentComponent = () => {
console.log(useContext(ApolloContext)) // <- returns client
...

return (
  <Child />
 )
}
```

Child component

```
import { ApolloContext } from "../context/apollo/ApolloContext";

const Child = () => {
 console.log(useContext(ApolloContext)) // <- returns null
...
 return (
  <div> hello </div>
)};
```

Comment: Show your `ApolloProvider` .... [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: And all component tree, it depends where the components are rendered, try reproduce in a sandbox

Comment: Why is there an `ApolloProvider` and then again a nested `ApolloContext.Provider` ? Are the two not related at all ? Generally a wrapper Provider class like `ApolloProvider` returns a `ApolloContext.Provider` component so alone `ApolloProvider` suffices.